# Java trying find the regex

Tags: java, regex

I trying I am trying to find a suitable regex expression to match all these pattern below. Could you help me.

S1234567A

1234567A

1234567 A

S 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 A

S-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-A

S 1234567 A

S 1234567A

the pattern can starts with G/T/S. number at the middle can be random but will be contain 7 digit, and the last alphabet also random with only 1 alphabet.

Thanks.

Comment: The second and third ones _don't_ start with G/T/S.  Additionally, without any counter-examples, `.*` would match all of them.

Comment: Hi Ramadhan, You could approach the problem in a different way. You could come up with a regex that only allows the characters, special characters are allowed. In your case, google for a regex in Java that allows `a-z,A-Z, - and spaces`. That would comply with the pattern you described above. Between, great to see you taking time to ask a question in SO. Here are some of the guidelines for forming a good question in So :-). Good luck and cheers.

Comment: The most restrictive pattern that matches all of those is: `^(?:S[ -]?)?1[ -]?2[ -]?3[ -]?4[ -]?5[ -]?6[ -]?7[ -]?A$`. See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zj4457/1). --- There are many regex's between that and the very loose `.*` that would fit your requirement. Only *you* can decide exactly how strict you want the regex to be, so *you* need to write the regex. I recommend going through some regex tutorials to learn how to write regex's.

Comment: Another way: `^[GTS]?([ ]|[-])?([1-7]|(1-2-3-4-5-6-7)|(1 2 3 4 5 6 7))+[- ]?A$`.

Comment: hey all, really appreciate for your help, i just edited my question. so basically the number in the middle and last alphabet can be random. hope you have another solution for me. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this regex:

```
^([GTS]{0,1}[ ]{0,1}[0-9]{7}[ ]{0,1}[A-Z])|(([GTS]{0,1}-([0-9]-){7}[A-Z]))|(([GTS]{0,1} ([0-9] ){7}[A-Z]))$
```

The first part:

```
([GTS]{0,1}[ ]{0,1}[0-9]{7}[ ]{0,1}[A-Z])
```

Matches the following:

```
S1234567A
9136013A
7102938 A
S 0849376 A
S 5840201A
```

The second part:

```
(([GTS]{0,1}-([0-9]-){7}[A-Z]))
```

For the `-`:

```
S-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-A
```

And the third part:

```
(([GTS]{0,1} ([0-9] ){7}[A-Z]))
```

For the spaces:

```
S 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 A
```

As it seems that some other combination of them like:
`S 1 2 3-4-5-6-7-A`
should not match.

Otherwise you could simplify it to:

```
^([GTS]{0,1}[ ]{0,1}[0-9]{7}[ ]{0,1}[A-Z])|(([GTS]{0,1}[- ]([0-9][- ]){7}[A-Z]))$
```

But only if it's ok that strings like `S 1 2 3-4-5-6-7-A` match.

And notice all this `[0-9]` can be replaced by `\d`, use the form you prefer.